# Java can't find symbol

Tags: java, object, compiler-construction, applet

This is my error message

```
test.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MouseAdapter
location: class test
        private class click extends MouseAdapter
                                    ^
test.java:19: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MouseEvent
location: class test.click
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
                                         ^
test.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable trayicon
location: class test
        trayicon.addMouseListener(new click());
        ^
3 errors
```

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class test extends JFrame
{

    private JFrame frame;

    public void init()
    {
        trayicon.addMouseListener(new click());
    }

        private class click extends MouseAdapter
        {
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
            {
                {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reproducing the error:

```
$cat >test.java <<. 
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class test extends JFrame
{

    private JFrame frame;

    public void init()
    {
        trayicon.addMouseListener(new click());
    }

        private class click extends MouseAdapter
        {
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
            {
                {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
.
$javac test.java 
test.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MouseAdapter
location: class test
        private class click extends MouseAdapter
                                    ^
test.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MouseEvent
location: class test.click
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
                                     ^
test.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable trayicon
location: class test
        trayicon.addMouseListener(new click());
        ^
3 errors
```

Adding the import

```
$ed test.java 
431
1i
import java.awt.event.*;
.
wq
456
$javac test.java 
test.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable trayicon
location: class test
        trayicon.addMouseListener(new click());
        ^
1 error
```

Declaring `trayicon` at line 13

```
$ed test.java 
456
13i
        JLabel trayicon = new JLabel();// or something that makes sense
.
wq
528
$javac test.java 
$
```

Fixed!

Resulting code:

```
$cat test.java 
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class test extends JFrame
{

    private JFrame frame;

    public void init()
    {
        JLabel trayicon = new JLabel();// or something that makes sense
        trayicon.addMouseListener(new click());
    }

        private class click extends MouseAdapter
        {
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
            {
                {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, you don't need lines 26 and 21:

```
$ed test.java 
633
26d
21d
wq
605
$javac test.java 
$
$cat test.java 
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class test extends JFrame
{

    private JFrame frame;

    public void init()
    {
        JLabel trayicon = new JLabel();// or something that makes sense
        trayicon.addMouseListener(new click());
    }

        private class click extends MouseAdapter
        {
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
            {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
```

**Edit:**

and you need to declare trayicon:

```
JLabel trayicon = new JLabel();
```

Comment: @user516805: Are the error messages exactly the same with this new import?  I find that hard to believe.

Comment: That should have worked. Can you try importing java.awt.event.MouseEvent ?

Answer (score 0):

adding to mellamokb, you are using a variable **trayicon** which is not declared anywhere.

So add

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
```

and declare **trayicon**

Comment: java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;



public class test2 extends JApplet
{
 private final int currentX = 0;


 public void init()
 {
  addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
 }
 
 public void paint (final Graphics g)
 {
  super.paint (g);
  
  g.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
 }
 
 private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter
 {
  
  currentX = e.getX();
 }
}